# How to export a Panel containing a Gridview control and an Image to a PDF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I Am having trouble exporting my panel containing a Gridview and Image to a PDF.Any Suggestions ?

This is my code for exporting my Gridview and it does it successfully.But i need to export my Gridview and my image above the Gridview which is both contained inside a panel.

```
 Using sw As New StringWriter()
                Using hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                    'To Export all pages
                    GridView1.AllowPaging = False
                    Me.LoadDataGrid()
                    GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
                    Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
                    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A2, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
                    Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
                    pdfDoc.Open()
                    htmlparser.Parse(sr)
                    pdfDoc.Close()
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf")
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
                    Response.Write(pdfDoc)
                    Response.[End]()
                End Using
            End Using
```

Comment: I have not used that before @Devcon .

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't realize it was an asp app :/